# flutter_google_maps Screen Coordinate to Map Coordinate

Tags: google-maps, flutter

For flutter apps using the flutter_google_map, is there a way to translate a point on the device screen to the corresponding coordinate on the map?

They do it internally when someone taps on the map widget they have to take the view coordinate and translate it to a map coordinate.  However, I cannot find the code for this process.  Has anyone found where that code is located?  (I'm still looking and I'll post it, if I find it.)

Comment: see [getLatLng()](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter/latest/google_maps_flutter/GoogleMapController/getLatLng.html)

Comment: @pskink I've been traveling and haven't had a chance to test, but it looks like it is exactly what I was looking for.  So, premature "thank you", and after I test it I will ask you to submit it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @pskink that was perfect!  Thank you very much!

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 0):

A full example of how to do this using [getLatLng()](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter/latest/google_maps_flutter/GoogleMapController/getLatLng.html).

```
LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) { 
  return MouseRegion(
    onHover: (event) async {    
      LatLng? position = await mapModel.mapController?.getLatLng(ScreenCoordinate(
      x: ((constraints.maxWidth) * (event.localPosition.dx / (constraints.maxWidth))).round(),
      y: ((constraints.maxHeight) * (event.localPosition.dy / constraints.maxHeight)).round(),
                      ));
     mapModel.setHoverSpot(position);
                   
   },
   child: GoogleMap(
     ...
    ),
  );
});
```